# Would it not be better to have people state their real identity at least in their profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

It appears to me that not requiring a real identity, at least in the profile, is reinforcing poor behavior in this forum. It seems many people hide behind their virtual moniker, tossing crap every which way as it suits their ego. Don't you think that at least requiring a real name in the profile would deter this behavior?

Comment: While i like this as an idea, it is never going to work. We don't have a way to check or enforce

Comment: Thank you Dr. Mayhem for your kind attention. Can't a so called 'true' id be linked to the authentication process like at least the person's email addr, but only show up in their profile. I'm ok with virtual monikers as long as it links to a real person. This forum is not an online video game correct? (Although the reputation point system seems to reflect that.)

Comment: Well, mods can see the email address, so in the event of had behaviour we do have a connection to an email address, however an email address is not necessarily a useful identifier as they are easy to create

Comment: What if the MOD is overstating their Policing duties?

Comment: Not sure i follow. Can we take this to chat

Comment: OOPs, what chat room?

Comment: On second thought, I don't see any incentive to hang in this forum anymore. It appears toxic to me to spend time trying to help someone only to have to go to battle with some other contributor's ego. Certainly not you, you are one of the good guys here. For me it appears, 'it is never going to work'

Comment: Considering the way the internet works, this seems to be one of the least drama/troll/jargon/hyperbole-filled places. What specific cases are you referring to?

Comment: Filzilla - there isn't an easy way to do confidential one to one chat other than through direct mod messaging, but the main music chat is easy if you are okay with that:http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room

Comment: Interestingly - we now seem to have hit a half way house at least.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619/233816

Answer (score 4):

There is no non-insane way to verify identify.  Is everyone supposed to go to the SE offices with their passport before being allowed an account?

People are also regularly discriminated against because of their real identities, and you can see examples from numerous sites (e.g., Twitter) that many people do not moderate their behavior online just because of a real name.

Answer (score -3):

Open-auth which is also used for logging into SE could be used to verify identity and "true" name.  OTOH, having a true name posted doesn't seem to stop some people from being rude.